# Segue Popover won't behave properly

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, segue

I'm trying to use Segue to present then dismiss a Popover view a `UIBarButtonItem` is clicked.

I've created a generic Segue that is not anchored to anything but the view and given it a name

I've Anchored the UIBarButtonItem in the Interface Builder to:

```
- (IBAction)clickedSettings:(id)sender {

    if(self.popSegue != nil) {
        [self.popSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        //Current says only a button may
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Settings" sender:sender];
    }
}
```

But when ever i click the button to display the Segue it gives me an error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIStoryboardPopoverSegue must be presented from a bar button item or a view.'**

It doesn't even hit my `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

I've read the following questions on stack:

1. [iOS:How to dismiss Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8656348/933887)
2. [UIBarButtonItem + popover segue creates multiple popovers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8598557/933887)

But i still get the same error. For the life of me i can't figure out what is going wrong

Comment: did u find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I take no credit for this since I got every bit of it from going through multiple StackOverflow threads, but I got this working with:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
- (IBAction) toggleSettingsInPopover: (id) sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *settingsPopoverSegue;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize settingsPopoverSegue = _settingsPopoverSegue;

- (IBAction) toggleSettingsInPopover: (id) sender {
    if( [self.settingsPopoverSegue.popoverController isPopoverVisible] ) {
        [self.settingsPopoverSegue.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated: YES];
        self.settingsPopoverSegue = nil;
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Settings" sender: sender];
    }
}

- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender {
    if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"Settings"] ) {
        if( [segue isKindOfClass: [UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]] )
            self.settingsPopoverSegue = (UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *) segue;
        MySettingsViewController *msvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        msvc.delegate = self;
    }
}
@end
```

In my storyboard I control-dragged from my settings bar button item to `MyViewController` and connected it to the `toggleSettingsInPopover` action. Then I control-dragged from `MyViewController` to the view for the settings to create the segue, set its type to `popover`, set its identifier to `Settings`, set its directions to up and left (the toolbar is at the bottom of the screen and the button is at the right end), then dragged from its `Anchor` to the bar button item I connected to the action.

Comment: Well, I have scoured many threads and your answer is definitely worthy of credit! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to anchor the segue to the UIBarButton by Ctrl-Dragging the Anchor Field from the segue Attribute Inspector to the UIBarButton.

If you do it the opposite way, Ctrl-Dragging from the Button to the Window to be shown you won't have a possibility to control the behaviour from the Popoverwindow.

(The important part is also in the last sentence of LavaSlider's Reply)